# How can I remove specific value pairs from an inline style tag using python?

Tags: python, regex, string, parsing, beautifulsoup

i am trying to parse some html that has some nasty inline styling.
it looks something like this

```
<span class="text_line" data-complex="0" data-endposition="4:2:86:5:0" data-position="4:2:74:2:0" style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -2.66667px; font-size: 24px !important; line-height: 40px; font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures; display: block; height: 40px; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 155px;">
```

I am trying to remove just the attribute-value pair `word-spacing: -2.66667px;`. Here is the catch there are several hundred of these lines and no two are the same. Sometimes  the spacing is `word-spacing: -4px` and sometimes `word-spacing: -3.78632px;` or some other random number.

I tried the beautiful soup, I figured out how to remove the whole tag, which is not what I wanted. I don't know how to do it with regular expressions. And I read that it's better to avoid trying to edit HTML with regex.

My idea right constitutes saving all the span tags to a variable using beautiful soup and then using `string.find()` to get the indexes of all the "w"'s in word-spacing and then finding the next semi column. Then after I have a list find a way to cut the string at those indexes and join the remnants back together. Maybe splitting at the ";" is better... I don't know any more at this point. The brain is a fried and tired. :P

```
    def __init__(self, first_index, last_index):
        self.first = first_index
        self.last = last_index
def getIndices(text, start_index):
    index = CutPointIndex(None, None)
    index.first = text.find("word-spacing", start_index, end_index)
    if(index.first != -1):
        index.last = text.find(";", index.first , end_index)
    return index
```

Given something like
`style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -3.71429px;"`

or   `style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -5px;`

or any other variation of values the expected outcome should be 
  `style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%;`

Comment: How does your html looks like? Can you share some sample?

Comment: @min2bro ` </span><span
            class="text_line" data-complex="0" data-endposition="4:2:58:0:0" data-position="4:2:43:2:0"
            style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -3.71429px; font-size: 24px !important; line-height: 40px; font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures; display: block; height: 40px; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 155px;">The quick brown <span data-lineend="1"
                data-selectable="0" data-singlespace="1"
                style="word-spacing: -12px; font-size: 24px !important; line-height: 40px;">  </span></span>`

Comment: What is expected output? Do you want to extract this word-spacing: -2.66667px or replace word-spacing: xxx px with empty string?

Comment: @min2bro yes! precisely!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe you might want to `re.sub` the variable `word-spacing`:

```
import re

regex = r"\s*word-spacing\s*:\s*[^;]*;"

test_str = '''
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -3.71429px;"
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -5px;"
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%;"

'''

print(re.sub(regex, "", test_str))
```

---

#### Output

```
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%;"
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%;"
style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%;"
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
> explained on the top right panel of
> [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/azzXIO/1/). If you'd like, you
> can also watch in [this
> link](https://regex101.com/r/azzXIO/1/debugger), how it would match
> against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: That seems to be able to select the first expression, can it find all matches?
https://regex101.com/r/9hQApv/1

Comment: Oh that's awesome thank you!
Ok, so if I want to set the global flag programatically. 
regex = r"\s*word-spacing\s*:\s*[^;]*;"g  would be the right way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You could match on elements with that attribute and remove that part.

I split the style attribute (for the relevant tags only) on `;` then recombine excluding the unwanted pair

```
';'.join([i for i in t['style'].split(';') if 'word-spacing' not in i])
```

but you could just as easily update the value for `word-spacing`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<span class="text_line" data-complex="0" data-endposition="4:2:86:5:0" data-position="4:2:74:2:0" style="font-family: scala-sans-offc-pro--; width: 100%; word-spacing: -2.66667px; font-size: 24px !important; line-height: 40px; font-variant-ligatures: common-ligatures; display: block; height: 40px; margin-left: 75px; margin-right: 155px;">
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')

for t in soup.select('[style*= word-spacing]'):
    t['style'] = ';'.join([i for i in t['style'].split(';') if 'word-spacing' not in i])
print(soup)
```

Reading:

1. https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#attributes
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: Thank you! I will read those links tomorrow and try that solution. Right now I used regex-replace with a batch script i made in visual code studio. Which makes it a two stage process. I'd like to get it be a  one stage process in pure python.